# Prevent Google from uploading pictures when connected to wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, google-photos

I noticed that pictures I took with my Android smartphone while connected to my home ADSL/wifi router were silently uploaded to Google Photos.

How can I disable this "feature" ?

Thank you.

Comment: Go to *Settings › Accounts* and tap your Google account. Check if *Google Photos* is listed there. If so, switch off the toggle next to it. That should turn off synchronisation for that app completely.

Comment: @Izzy strangely, Google photos is not listed there.

Comment: That's weird. I cannot check, my devies either run Google-free or at least have most of the GApps disabled/removed (including Photos).

Comment: @Gulbahar BTW the picture uploading is a free feature that is provided by Google to save your pictures to the cloud so that you can access them from any device using your Google account. These pictures are only accessable to you, and anyone who has access to your Google account. Therefore i suggest u keep this feature so that in a case where you lose your phone or it's data, you will still have access to them. You are obviously free to choose as you wish.

Comment: @Abochur "only accessable to you" is very much doubtable (at least Google staff has access as well, and who knows what "scanners" run over them). I'd rather suggest turning that off and syncing with your own resources :)

Comment: @Izzy I meant to say that it's not accessable publicly online. I'm sure that you'll agree that anything that we do in our phones is accessable to someone, wether it's an app developer or the government. The only way we can get around that, is by going to an island with no technology and hope that they won't come spying on us...

Comment: @Abochur I wouldn't say "is accessible to someone" (unless that someone on my device is myself). I'd at least include a "possibly". One can take precautions and limit the "data flow" (e.g. use LineageOS with no GApps, and carefully select your apps). That doesn't make it impossible but much more unlikely that someone gets "unauthorized access". I'm not one of those fatalists saying "I don't care, they know anyhow" (wrong approach ;)

Comment: Btw, did any of the answers below, stop the uploading?

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer Alex has posted (which is correct), if you still want to upload a particular photo to Drive after disabling sync, long press the photo- (select it)  and you will see a share option using which you can share to your drive.

This comes in handy when you have globally disabled sync for photos but want to save some photos to drive

Answer (score 1):

To stop Google photos from syncing your pictures, do the following:

1. Open the Google photos app
2. Open the menu on the top right
3. Open settings
4. Press on "Back up & sync"
5. Toggle off the 'backup and sync' option.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate syncing of photos or disable the Google Photos app (you will not be able to use it after that).