# How to create an album without uploading to Google Photos cloud

Tags: sync, accounts, google-photos

On my Android device, Xiaomi Redmi note 8, the sync with Google account is disabled. For Photos, too. Today, I created a new album on the photos and noticed that it started to upload the photos, and it is already on the wifi. This is strange since the syncs are closed.

I want to prevent this, looked for the options, and couldn't find one. I've seen [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/188706/189549) and its answer, however, none is helpful.

My guess, Google covertly implemented this feature so that any album other than the main, is uploaded to the cloud. Is this correct?

Can we create an album without uploading it to the cloud?

Is there a way to prevent this, other than the temporary Wi-Fi disablement?

---

Note to the covert adversary:

1. There is no notification for this, just show a dialog to choose. Give us our liberty!
2. On Accounts& Sync settings, even the sync is closed, once you touch one of the items, the item immediately starts to sync. What a shame!

Comment: @beeshyams that is an annoying solution. I've blocked it with Netguard and the photos application seems that it is not accepting that it cannot reach the net. It tries to keep uploading and we have a notification running indefinitely.

Comment: Sorry for that. Should have suggested after checking. Google is very troublesome. Will revert if I can think of something +1

Comment: @beeshyams If the photos application stays in the background, the notification stays to indicate the upload try. If the photo application is killed, then the notification is gone.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be an option if northing better turns up